# What is the meaning of Drive, Drive Compact, Focus, Focus Compact in Style Guide

Tags: style-guide, design-system

When I read this article, https://design.lyft.com/building-a-design-system-library-3a1f0d09088f#2cf8 found following image.

Its talking about **Frame Name**

> The frame name is the top-level grouping of the component, usually the
> size (ie. Buttons have 4 sizes: Focus, Focus Compact, Drive, and Drive
> Compact).

[image: naming structure of button component]

Middle of the image, there is a list called

- Drive,
- Drive Compact,
- Focus,
- Focus Compact,

what are they?

Comment: According to the article:  "Buttons have 4 sizes: Focus, Focus Compact, Drive, and Drive Compact"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about how a specific company labels items and isn't something that applies to the broader UX community.

Answer (score 4):

The article continues and states:

> The frame name is the top-level grouping of the component, usually the size (ie. Buttons have 4 sizes: Focus, Focus Compact, Drive, and Drive Compact).

It's just terminology they've established for their sizes of elements. I'd imagine it's used in part with their app having two main states for their drivers: driving or not driving. The interface concerns (e.g. size of buttons) are very different when considering these factors. I'm sure their design guidelines probably talk about that at some point.